# For a given word, Predict the cluster and get the nearest words from the cluster

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means, word2vec, supervised-learning

I have trained my corpus on w2v and k-means following the instructions given this link.

https://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/k-means-clustering-example-word2vec/

What I am want to do this 
a. find the cluster ID for a given word
b. get the top 20 nearest words from the cluster for the given word.

I have figured out how to the words in a given cluster. What I want is to find out the words that are closer to my given word in the given cluster.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked guide is, with its given data, a bit of misguided. You can't get meaningful 100-dimensional word-vectors (the gensim `Word2Vec` class default) from a mere 30-word corpus. The results from such a model will be nonsense, useless for clustering or other downstream steps – so any tutorial purporting to show this process, with true results, should be using far more data.

If you are in fact using far more data, and have succeeded in clustering words, the `Word2Vec` model's `most_similar()` function will give you the top-N (default 10) nearest-words for any given input word. (Specifically, they will be returned as `(word, cosine_similarity)` tuples, ranked by highest `cosine_similarity`.)

The `Word2Vec` model is of course oblivious to the results of clustering, so you would have to filter those results to discard words outside the cluster of interest.

I'll assume that you have some lookup object `cluster`, that for `cluster[word]` gives you the cluster ID for a specific word. (This might be a dict, or something that does a KMeans-model `predict()` on the supplied vector, whatever.) And, that `total_words` is the total number of words in your model. (For example: `total_words = len(w2v_model.wv)`. Then your logic should be roughly like

```py
target_cluster = cluster[target_word]
all_similars = w2v_model.wv.most_similar(target_word, topn=total_words)
in_cluster_similars = [sim for sim in all_similars 
                       if cluster[sim[0]] = target_cluster]
```

If you just want the top-20 results, clip to `in_cluster_similars[:20]`.

Comment: Thanks @gojomo. Your code worked. As you said, I will have to have a good enough dataset to get the desired result. And I am working on it. The purpose of is find word bundle from a given topic. For topic modelling I am using LDA. And the idea is create clusters of each topic and get the word bundle of each topic. Do let me know if this helps you in suggesting a better approach. Thanks